# Split binary data into byte array in Perl

Tags: perl, split, binary-data, unpack

I basically wanted to convert a binary string to an array/list of bytes (*so as to allow indexing, and avoid using `substr`, because its syntax complicates things for me*), and I came up with the following [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that/231#231):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

# Use open ':raw';      # Unknown PerlIO layer class ':raw'
use open IO => ':raw';

binmode(STDIN);
binmode(STDOUT);

# Create original 8-bit byte array/list
my @atmp = (0x80, 0x23, 0x14, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x43, 0x00, 0x00);

# Make a copy of portion
my @atmp2 = (0) x 2;
@atmp2[0..1] = @atmp[7..8];

# Print output
print "Copied atmp2 contents as hex: " . join(", ", unpack("H2"x2, pack("C"x2,@atmp2))) . "\n";
print "Copied atmp2 as ushort (16bit) int: " . unpack("S", pack("C"x2, @atmp2));
# doublecheck value by routing through printf with format specifier:
printf(" [%d]\n", unpack("S", pack("C"x2, @atmp2)));


# Now, the same data as string:
my $indata = "\x80\x23\x14\x0d\x0a\x00\x00\x80\x43\x00\x00";

# Create byte array (by converting string $indata to array/list with `split`)
my @btmp = split('',$indata);
print "lastindex: " . $#btmp . "\n";

# Make a copy of portion
my @btmp2 = (0) x 2;
@btmp2[0..1] = @btmp[7..8];

# Print output
print "Copied btmp2 contents as hex: " . join(", ", unpack("H2"x2, pack("C"x2,@btmp2))) . "\n";
print "Copied btmp2 as ushort (16bit) int: " . unpack("S", pack("C"x2, @btmp2));
# doublecheck value by routing through printf with format specifier:
printf(" [%d]\n", unpack("S", pack("C"x2, @btmp2)));
```

Running this code results with:

```
$ perl test.pl
Copied atmp2 contents as hex: 80, 43
Copied atmp2 as ushort (16bit) int: 17280 [17280]
lastindex: 10
Argument "M-\0" isn't numeric in pack at test.pl line 38.
Argument "C" isn't numeric in pack at test.pl line 38.
Copied btmp2 contents as hex: 00, 00
Copied btmp2 as ushort (16bit) int: 0 [0]
```

How do I get the second part (btmp2) to behave the same as the first part (atmp2)?

Answer (score 7):

It turns out, when using `split`, it does indeed create an array with the same bytes as in the original string; however, it also seems to mark the resulting array somehow as "textual", so further processing fails with "Argument not numeric".

The answer is simply to replace the `split` line with one that uses `unpack`, instead:

```
- my @btmp = split('',$indata);
+ my @btmp = unpack('C*',$indata);
```

... and after that, all works as expected (both printouts are identical). Interestingly, in both cases, "lastindex" (for the array derived from a string) will be shown as 10 (which made me think something may be wrong with the `binmode`, which is why all those statements are there in the code).

Comment: Well it did help me, thanks! I can't believe how difficult it was to answer this simple question but I couldn't find a single Perl document, man page, or tutorial that explained this clearly...